# NGINX Multi-Tenant Configuration With Certbot SSL & Allowing Multiple Root Domains

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I've NGINX 1.18.0 running on uBuntu 20.10. I wish to configure it to allow unlimited subdomains for my multi-tenant application.

I use the following configuration file for most of my single-tenant applications; and it works fine:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html/public;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        charset utf-8;

        server_name mydomain.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

I've two questions -

Question #1. How do I modify this configuration file to allow unlimited subdomain? My best attempt so far is modifying the `server_name` block as follows:

```
server_name mydomain.com *.mydomain.com
```

Followed by running `certbot --nginx` to obtain the wildcard certificate. However, this only works for the root domain; and not on any subdomain.

Would appreciate any help with this.

Question #2: My users would want to map their own domains or subdomains to their respective subdomain on mydomain.com.

For example: abc.com or xyz.abc.com pointing to subdomain1.mydomain.com

How would the configuration change in this case?

PS: This configuration seems to be quite common with every multi-tenant application. I'm however not able to find any solution that works.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts, here's what worked:-

1. Keep the server_name just to the bare minimum viz:

`server_name domain.com`

We don't need to have wildcards here.

2. Install certbot and then run this command-

```
sudo certbot certonly \
  --agree-tos \
  --email me@domain.com \
  --manual \
  --preferred-challenges=dns \
  -d *.domain.com -d domain.com \
  --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
```

You'll be asked to update your `TXT` records. This is tricky. After you update your TXT record, you must wait till the records are propagated properly. You must wait on the command prompt; resisting the urge to press 'ENTER' key to continue. Just don't do that, until you're sure the records have been updated.

3. Certbot will install wildcard certificate for your domain. Restart NGINX and visit your `domain.com` and .domain.com. You should see any subdomain loading with HTTPS.